# I am getting this error when I lunching flutter firebase on IOS

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, dart-pub

I am getting this error when I debugging my project:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build failed due to concurrent builds, will retry in 2 seconds.
Xcode build done.                                           71.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Uncategorized (Xcode): Existing file at -resultBundlePath "/var/folders/55/2zqsxlpd30g_hc3wj0b_f_5r0000gn/T/flutter_tools.Fvu6pR/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirtjaczA/temporary_xcresult_bundle.xcresult"
2

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

I am also getting this message when I Execute

```
terminal: Pod Install.
    !] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).
```

[image]